# Android studiogradle project sync failed

Tags: android

hi guys i am a newbie in Android Studio and i have a problem with my gradle project it brings up this message;
 Could not get unknown property '' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support', name='animated-vector-drawable', version='25.2.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.Kindly Assist. 
code for app level gradle build

```js
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sarah_njeri.theroscaapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'''


    compile 'com.android.support-compact:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'



    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post the full logcat if you can or your app level Gradle Build

Comment: @NovoLucas i have posted the code for app level gradle build

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'''
```

you have added two extra `'` there just delete it

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
```